# How to set Spark application exit status?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, exit-code, spark-submit

I'm writing a spark application and run it using spark-submit shell script (using yarn-cluster/yarn-client)

As I see now, exit code of spark-submit is decided according to the related yarn application - if SUCCEEDED status is 0, otherwise 1.

I want to have the option to return another exit code - for a state that my application succeeded with some errors.

Is it possible? to return different exit code from the application?

I tried to use System.exit() but didn't succeed...

Thanks.

Comment: The answer posted in this question might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428145/do-exit-codes-and-exit-statuses-mean-anything-in-spark

Comment: Are you still getting this error? What number are you passing in?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in client mode but not in cluster mode. You have a workaround for cluster mode.

My answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376793/pass-custom-exitcode-from-yarn-cluster-mode-spark-to-cli/41428720#41428720) should help you.

Comment: Read that and still don't understand how using yarn-client will help in that case? still we'l get the yarn status..

Answer (score 0):

If you run in cluster mode, spark-submit ends immediately returning submission ID as part of json, and do not waits for the application status. After this you can query the status by

```
 spark-submit --status [submission ID]
```

If run in local or standalone modes you should be able to get this the exit code from spark-submit process.